# Java RMI - When to create a Stub, start Registry and specify Codebase?

Tags: java, rmi

When to create a Stub, start Registry and specify Codebase?

I have created a RMI application. My simple application works. I have the RemoteObjInterface.class's package in my buildpath for the Client and the Server packages. I first start the Server application and then the Client application.

However, I have looked at other examples in the internet and I see them starting the registry, creating a Stub and specifying a codebase.

The following is my program:

The "**RemoteObjInterface.class**" is my Interface, "**RemoteObjImplementation.class**" is my Server and "**Client.class**" is my Client.

```
public interface RemoteObjInterface extends Remote {
    public String someMethod() throws RemoteException;
        }
```

---

```
public class RemoteObjImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
    RemoteObjInterface {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final int PORT = 1099;
   private static Registry registry;

public RemoteObjImplementation() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    }

@Override
public String someMethod() throws RemoteException {

    return new String("Hello");
    }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);

    registry.bind(RemoteObjInterface.class.getSimpleName(),
            new RemoteObjImplementation());

     }
}
```

---

```
public class Client {
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 1099;
    private static Registry registry;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(HOST, PORT);

 RemoteObjInterface remoteApi = (RemoteObjInterface) registry.lookup(RemoteObjInterface.class.getSimpleName());

    System.out.println("Message = " +
            remoteApi.someMethod();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When to create a Stub

Creating a stub is a side-effect of exporting the remote object, which in turn is a side-effect of constructing it if it extends `UnicastRemoteObject`.

> start Registry

When you want to start it. Before you start calling `bind()` or `rebind()` for example.

> and specify Codebase?

You don't need to use this feature at all, it is optional. If you want your clients to be able to download classes dynamically rather than distributing them to the client ahead of time, specify the `java.rmi.server.codebase` system property in the server JVM before you export any remote objects (including Registries), and make sure it points to a URL that is accessible by both the Registry and the client.

Comment: @EJP...sorry for not being clear. Anyways, you have already answered my question. In the examples I saw in the internet, they seem to be using some kind of a RMI plugin in Eclipse. So, like I said before in my question, through the menu option in Eclipse they were creating a stub through the menu option when they were already extending their RemoteObjImplementation object with UnicastRemoteObject. Usually we need to create a stub if we did not directly extend and use UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(RemoteObjImplementation);

Comment: If you mean *generate* a stub *class*, just change to super(0) and you don't need one. A dynamic stub is used instead. See the preamble to UnicastRemoteObject.